# Conditional expectation and variance.

Tags: probability-distributions

> We are given that $\operatorname E(Y|x)$ is linear in $x$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Y|x)$ is a constant.
>   We need to prove that $\operatorname{Var}(Y|x) = (\operatorname{Var}(y))^{2} (1-r)^{2}$ where $r$ is the correlation coefficient.

I tried writing $\operatorname{Var}(Y|x)$ as:
$$\operatorname{Var}(Y|x) = \operatorname E(Y^{2}|x)-E(Y|x)^{2}$$
But I have no idea how to proceed further...

---

> $\operatorname E(Y|x)$ is linear in $x$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Y|x)$ is constant [...]

This statement means something but I am not able to figure it out... Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The *minimum mean-square error (MMSE) estimator* of $Y$, given that $X$ has value $x$ is $E[Y\mid X = x]$.  The **linear** *minimum mean-square error (LLMSE) estimator* (LLMSE) is of the form
$$r \left(\sqrt{\frac{\operatorname{var}(Y)}{\operatorname{var}(X)}}
\right)(x - \mu_X) + \mu_Y.$$
The mean-square error of the LLMSE estimator is 
$\operatorname{var}(Y)(1-r^2)$.

Here you are being told that the MMSE estimator of $Y$ given that
$X=x$ is a linear function of $x$ (note that linear in this context
means of the form $ax+b$). What do you think the LMMSE estimator
is, and what is its variance?